# How to verify the color of the element in selenium RC

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-rc, ui-automation

Need to verify the color of the element when hovering on web elemet where the style information available in the CSS file

Sample:

```
<a href="foo.com" class="color-set" />

color-set {
color: #047fe9;
}
```

So how can i get the information from CSS file via Selenium RC

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assert this:

```
assertTrue(Selenium.IsElementPresent("css=color-set[color:#047fe9]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `execute_script` to get the css. If you have jQuery:

```
color = driver.execute_script("jQuery('.color-set').css('background-color')")
assert_it...
```

If not jQuery:

```
color = driver.execute_script("elm = document.getElementsByClassName('color-set'); return window.getDefaultComputedStyle(elm).getPropertyValue('background-color');")
assert_it...
```

Comment: i need to execute with RC. not sure of using it with jQuery

Comment: @Giri if RC accept `execute_script` you can run it. jQuery is related to site javascript library, I also aded for without jQuery